# Not Completely Sure About Why to Use Polymorphic Reference

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

Ok so basically I have generic type T here which implements Comparable interface. Now say you want to iterate over an array of T objects. I've seen examples where you use T reference when iterating and other examples where you have Comparable reference, which is possible since T implements Comparable.

My question is, why would you choose one other the other; is there any real practical reason for choosing Comparable reference rather than T?

The example shows iteration over array, one with Comparable reference, other with T reference.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
        void baz(T[] biz)
{

    for (Comparable d: biz)
    {
        System.out.println(d); //Comparable reference
     }

    for (T foo: biz)
    {
      System.out.println(foo); //T reference        
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: I don't see much difference between the two, other then your intentions are more obvious in the first loop (although something like `Comparable<T>` would be more accurate)

Comment: So what you're saying is, functionally, there is no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Comparable` reference only when you want to compare the objects. Otherwise use the `T` reference, since you may want to pass the object to some other method that takes a `T` object.

Remember, standard inheritance rules apply here - you can cast a `T` reference to `Comparable` (because you specified that `T` must extend `Comparable`), but you can't cast every `Comparable` reference to `T`.

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `System.out.println`, it takes `Object`, which both `Comparable<T>` and `T` satisfy (since all objects are instances of `Object`), so you could have written `for (Object foo : biz)` and it'd have worked in this case.

In the general case, choose the most general type that works for the operations you need to invoke.